# Data scraping of an aria-label with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From the following, i am trying to extract the analysts price targets.
I am interested in the information present inside the aria-label.

I tried multiple versions of `BeautifulSoup` I found online with the following setup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'XXXXX'} >> XXXXX replaced with actual
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

1. The aria-label seems to be between a `'div'` and a `'class'`, so I tried the following:

   ```
     target = soup.find('div', {'class':'Px(10px)'})
   ```

Result = None

2. It is inside a section, so I tried the following:

   ```
     target = soup.find('section', attrs={'data-test':'price-targets'})
   ```

Result = None

3. Then I tried to go even upper, using the ID:

   ```
     target = soup.find('div', {'id':'mrt-node-Col2-5-QuoteModule'}).find_all('div')[0]
   ```

Result = `< div data-react-checksum="2049647463" data-reactid="1" data-reactroot="" id="Col2-5-QuoteModule-Proxy">< span data-reactid="2">< /span>< /div>`

Thus, I am getting closer with option 3, but I receive an error when I modify the `find_all` div index

Is there any solution or turnaround to extract the 4 data present in the aria-label?

The numbers next to `'Low'`, `'Current'`, `'Average'` & `'High'` are my target.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: Thank you for the edit of my first post Ann ! I posted the URL

Comment: You'll need to use `selenium`, as the elements you are trying to get are dynamic, and `Beautifulsoup` can't handle dynamic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `selenium` might consume time to iterate, I found a second possible solution to my issue which is to get the source code of the page using `requests`, and search for the data with a combination of json & regex.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ann Zen mentioned in commented the website is rendering elements and data dynamically and `Beautifulsoup` can't handle it alone using `Selenium` will wait till the time app is loaded and then try to get the element

Example [web-scraping-with-selenium](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/web-scraping-with-selenium)

Comment: Please give a solution with Selenium :)

Comment: @UtpalDutt Thank you very much for the information ! I will start learning about Selenium and wait for your solution at the same time :)